# PHP Zend Framework: Internal Server Error 500 on localhost when trying to run "Lucene.php" on browser

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am running windows 7 and I have a fresh install of Zend framework. On a new php file called 'search.php' I am trying to build a search application using Zend_Search_Lucene with the first line being:

```
<?php require_once "C:...\Zend\Search\Lucene.php";?>
```

What I see on the browser when I run this code is internal server error 500..I then discovered that I get this error whenever I try to run some of the files in Zend library by itself and this is what caused the error I mentioned..i.e ERROR 500 on localhost/Zend/Search/Lucene.php, localhost/Zend.../blabla.php..

Some of the files however, did not display this 500 server error when run on the browser. ie: localhost/Zend/ProgressBar.php shows an empty page, which is fine since I assume there are not any 'echo'es in the code. This is actually what I expected when I ran lucene.php on the browser...

Can somebody experienced let me know how this can happen? Why do I get internal server error instead of exception? How do I check if my search application that uses "Lucene.php" file runs properly regardless of this internal 500 server error? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem :) After looking at the error traces, the internal server error is because the code `<?php require_once "C:...\Zend\Search\Lucene.php";?>` tries to access a particular code inside "Lucene.php" that contains a relative path to the Zend library folder =`require_once('Zend\Search\Document\...');` and the server does not know the path to the file. What needed to be fixed was actually my php.ini file, on the include_path i added `;C:\php5\pear;C:\Server\www\.....\ZendFramework\library`..Now it shows empty page instead of internal server error.

+1 @Arend: The error reporting function is really useful! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to turn on error reporting:

**on the fly**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**in php.ini** (probably different for php and cli)

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = 1
```

For more information see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Zend's code relies on their autoloader. You get an error, since you don't initialize it, then in Zend_Search_Lucene it tries to instanciate a nonexistent class.

This should do the trick:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
self::$zendLoaded = true;
```

Comment: I added your code to my php file and it still throws the same internal server error..However, like I said, Loader.php by itself runs fine on the browser (shows white empty page)

Comment: Loader by itself just defines the class, does nothing else. No wonder it works (shows an empty white page with http 200). Enable display_errors and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment answers, I re-use Maerlyn's code :

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

`self::$zendLoaded = true;` cannot work as `self` is not defined her.

According to the ZF documentation, if your path is set correctly, these 2 lines should be enough.